# Upload file node js with sizelimit

Tags: node.js, forms, formidable

I made a simple html form to upload an image.
I'm trying to use the formidable middleware to handle my image.

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
var filename = req.body.pid + ".jpg";
//Formidable uploads to operating systems tmp dir by default
form.uploadDir = "/src/main/images";       //set upload directory
form.keepExtensions = true;     //keep file extension

form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        if (bytesReceived > MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE) {
            console.log('### ERROR: FILE TOO LARGE');
        }
});

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

    //Formidable changes the name of the uploaded file
    fs.rename(files.fileUploaded.path, filename);
});
```

I'm doubting on how to handle the renaming of the file correctly as not all files will be jpg-files. But I really need to rename the file to a standard name.

Also, I want to limit the filesize using the form.on. Is there a better way to do this?